# Inserir conteúdo HTML na janela modal com JQuery

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou carregando conteúdo de um arquivo JSON, fazendo a formatação com JQuery e fazendo a inserção dentro do Bootstrap modal, o problema é que não aprece a formatação CSS usada.

Código para carregar o JSON

```
$('.button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();     
    $.getJSON('teste/teste.json', function(data) {
        var content  = '<div class="media">';
            content += '<img src="../../assets/other_img/bot-image.png" class="mr-3 mt-3 rounded-circle" style="width:60px;">';
            content += '<div class="media-body">';
            content += '<p>'+data.greeting+'</p>';
            content += '</div>';
            content += '</div>';

            $.each(data.menu, function(index, value)    {
                content += '<p class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">'+value+'</p>';  
            });

        $("#messageSent").html(content);    
    });

    $('.modal').modal('show'); 
});
```

Modal com conteúdo carregado e sem a formatação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual seria a formatação CSS usada? Pelo visto aí, as tags estão sendo inseridas em formato de texto.

Comment: Tentou verificar se o erro é essa forma como tu está passando a tua variável content ? Por exemplo, ao invés de inserir esse content, tenta inserir um html qualquer nesse modal e vE se dá certo. tipo um <p> abcdefgsdasdsa <p>, dá uma debugada ai e me diz o que acontece

Comment: Certifique-se que o elemento que possui o id `messageSent` é uma div.